How to use IIF in ORDER BY Queries for Azure Cosmos DB
I have items in my cosmosdb and I want to order them by the orderStatus. RECEIVED items will be listed first, then PROCESSING items, and then COMPLETED items.
Here is the query I have written. But unfortunately, it does not work.
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE c.orderStatus IN ('RECEIVED', 'PROCESSING', 'COMPLETED')
ORDER BY IIF(c.orderStatus = 'RECEIVED', 1, 
        IIF(c.orderStatus = 'PROCESSING', 2, 3))

I checked the documentation to find out if the way I wrote is a valid SQL for Cosmos DB or not. Found nothing. Any suggestion or alternative approach to the query?

The ORDER BY must be able to be served by an index.
In this case the order you want happens to be exactly reverse alphabetical anyway so you can just do
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE c.orderStatus IN ('RECEIVED', 'PROCESSING', 'COMPLETED')
ORDER BY c.orderStatus DESC

If this isn't always the case (perhaps you have additional order statuses not shown) you could add a computed property that returns the numeric sort order per order status (perhaps with your nested IIF expression) and include that in the indexing policy and then you can sort by that.
